# Add a “re-render markdown” button to posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown-rendering

This button could allow people to re-render the markdown if a bug is fixed in the parser.

To prevent DoS attacks, it could be available only to people with a certain amount of rep.

Screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Or, just edit the post. That will re-render it.

Comment: @Oded This way you wouldn’t bump the post.

Comment: What's an issue with legitimately bumping the post by editing?

Comment: @nicael Sometimes posts don’t need edits.

Comment: There are a more important buttons that could be added to the bottom of posts, which'd be used much more often too, like "timeline". That makes this FR seem too trivial to me. Furthermore, when more privileged users get the delete, protect and close buttons, adding a button with such large text makes that space look cramped and bad UX and all that stuff.

Comment: @TIPS: “timeline” is available, just click “**edited** x ago.”

Comment: TIPS did mean timeline, not revisions. And the timeline doesn't have a button indeed.

Comment: @nicael Oh. Got it.

Comment: E.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/280177/timeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you already can click edit, add a letter and remove it again so as the markdown re-renders and save the edit, and also the fact that it's not that the markdown bugs aren't fixed daily, I don't think there's any need in this feature.

Comment: This isn't feasible for sites, especially metas, where you don't have edit privileges. But wanting to refresh the cache is a legitimate thing: refreshing the cache when the post includes an auto-formatted title link to a deleted question will change the link back to a plain, unformatted URL link.